# error in nest build untyped module when using declare module

Tags: nestjs

I get this error when running nest build in ubuntu server. but it local no problem

```
src/user/middleware/current-user.middleware.ts:15:16 - error TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'express' resolves to an untyped module at '/home/mehrad/icnet-server/node_modules/express/index.js', which cannot be augmented.

15 declare module 'express' {
                  ~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error(s).
```